# Autofocus in Blackberry ported app

Tags: camera, autofocus

I have implemented [this](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) ocr library, Its working fine in android but when I port the app in blackberry , Auto focus is not working. Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

For Android you can directly compile your library using the NDK, then either write your app in Java and call your library via JNI, or write the whole app in C++ using the NDK.

I believe you are out of luck on Blackberry, for this platform you'll need to rewrite your library in Java, as neither apps or libs can be written in C++.

Comment: I already compiled using ndk. but problem is in library there is a method called camera.autoFocus(this). this is working in android but not in blackberry.

Comment: @AmarbirSingh you did not answer the question. It said that is working FINE. Just the auto-focus is not working.

Comment: I did it by making focus mode fixed.  parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_FIXED); Thanks

Comment: @ZulfiqarChandio It's your mistake that you didn't done the R&D and just post the problem. Well for answering on auto-focus how will i get to know which parameters you are using without seeing the code.